# Docker and Django – keep everything up to date & secure

Tags: python, django, docker, security

I am new to Docker and begin to understand how that whole thing works. My final goal is to deploy my Django project (which at the moment is running locally) to Google Code Run or a similar service, but there is still a way to go.

Actually, thanks to [this book](https://djangoforprofessionals.com/docker/), I already got my project running within a Docker container locally on my Mac, which is great.

My Dockerfile starts with

```
FROM python:3.8
```

and contains

```
COPY Pipfile Pipfile.lock /code/
RUN pip install pipenv && pipenv install --system
```

So every time I build my container, updates which are available for Linux, Python, Django and other packages I am using are included automatically, I guess (unless I declare otherwise e.g. for packages in my Pipfile).

The idea is to develop the app locally and test everything using Docker on my Mac. When it comes to updates, I have to check if everything is still consistent. If everything works fine locally, I (later) can deploy the container to somewhere else and everything should be fine.

Am I basically right or did I miss something important?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one important thing to keep track of is that the base images (`ubuntu:18.04`, `python:3.8`, and so on) occasionally get updates.  You need to make sure you `docker pull` the base image to get those updates; if you don't then you will build a new application image on top of the older base image you already have.  [`docker build`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/) has a `--pull` option that can automate this.

Also remember that the `Pipfile.lock` has extremely specific package versions in it, so you will need to periodically update this to get dependencies (for example, with [`pipenv update`](https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/basics/#example-pipenv-upgrade-workflow)).

The overall strategy of developing the Python application locally, using the standard packaging tools, and then building an image around that is generally a good approach.